# Trying to Insert an "h1" Before Another Specific "h1" With an Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

The specific line of code I need help with is labeled, but I've included the entire function for context. The expected output of the specified line of code should be as follows: I would like to insert the element `newNode` before the element `"#" + nextRank + "A"` (`nextRank` is defined as a capital letter, just as `rank` is). I believe the error in my code is coming from the syntax of `nextRank` on the specific line, but I could be wrong. Doe's anyone know how I could fix this?

```
//rank is a capital letter (EX: "A")
//nodeField is a div which only parents h1's.

function addNode(rank) {
    var alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
    var nextRank = alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(rank) + 1];
    
    if ($('#nodeField>h1[id^="${rank}"]').length) {
        var aI = alphabet.indexOf($('#nodeField>h1[id^="${rank}"]:last-child')[$('#nodeField>h1[id^="${rank}"]:last-child').length - 1]) + 1;
    } else {
        var aI = 0;
    }
    
    var newNode = document.createElement("h1");
    newNode.innerHTML = 0;
    newNode.id = rank + alphabet[aI];
    
    if ($(`#nodeField>h1[id^="${nextRank}"]`).length > 0) {
        
        //I need help with correcting the statement below!
        document.getElementById("nodeField").insertBefore(newNode, $("#" + nextRank + "A"));

    } else {
        document.getElementById("nodeField").appendChild(newNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up jQuery and pure JS elements. There are two ways to insert a new element before.

With pure JS:

```js
var newNode = document.createElement("h1");
newNode.innerHTML = 0;
newNode.id = "rankId";

document.getElementById("myDiv").insertBefore(newNode, document.getElementById("myInnerDiv"));
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="myInnerDiv">inner div</div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

In your case:

```
document.getElementById("nodeField").insertBefore(newNode, document.getElementById(nextRank + "A"));
```

---

With jQuery:

```js
var newNode = document.createElement("h1");
newNode.innerHTML = 0;
newNode.id = "rankId";

$(newNode).insertBefore($("#myInnerDiv"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="myInnerDiv">inner div</div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

In your case:

```
$(newNode).insertBefore($("#" + nextRank + "A"))
```

Comment: Neither of these cases work. It seems your code should've worked, so I'm going to check the rest of my code to ensure everything else is working properly. Thank you for you're help.